# How to switch between multiple CSS animations?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I have many sprites with different animation frames and times.

I would like to use those different styles in a same place.

I've tried to do this in a div element changing the class

**file1.css**

```
.hi1 {
    width: 800px;  
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("spritesONE.png");
    animation: play 20s steps(8) infinite;
   }
  @keyframes play {
          from { background-position:    0px; }
          to { background-position: -100px; }
   }
```

**file2.css**

```
.hi2 {
    width: 500px;  
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("spritesTWO.png");
    animation: play 2s steps(5) infinite;
   }
  @keyframes play {
          from { background-position:    0px; }
          to { background-position: -100px; }
   }
```

**html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file1.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file2.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file3.css" /> 
...
<div id="test" class="hi1"></div>
```

**js**

```
document.getElementById('test').className="hi2"; //CHANGE TO CLASS hi1, hi3, ..
```

*it changes the class but at including multiple CSS, the animations get broken...*

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to show the issue? Also I'm not sure what the benefit of breaking the css into different files is. Why not have a single file seeing as the classnames are not the same, so there is a differentiation there already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking that the issue is that you're using the same keyframe animation name. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes),

> If multiple keyframe sets exist for a given name, the last one
>   encountered is used.

Trying giving them unique names, such as:

```
.hi1 {
    width: 800px;  
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("spritesONE.png");
    animation: hi1-play 20s steps(8) infinite;
   }
  @keyframes hi1-play {
          from { background-position:    0px; }
          to { background-position: -100px; }
   }

.hi2 {
    width: 500px;  
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("spritesTWO.png");
    animation: hi2-play 2s steps(5) infinite;
   }
  @keyframes hi2-play {
          from { background-position:    0px; }
          to { background-position: -100px; }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to prefix both the "animation" shorthand properties as well as the @keyframes declarations to get the animations to work but this seems to work fine (in Chrome) even with the two identical @keyframe declarations. I would recommend removing or renaming one of them anyways since you don't need two, but I suspect your problem more has to do with the way you're applying the classnames - the styles from one of your files are likely not getting applied to the element correctly. Try putting all the styles in one file to start with and get it working there first, then separate them afterwards if you like.